# Distribution (group) comparison based on PCA

Tags: distributions, pca, nonparametric

I am looking for a way to compare the first the *k* principal components belonging to two separate groups of two-dimensional data, in order to see how similar the two groups are. I do not know which method to use to do this properly.

Googe showed me several, including [Between-Group Comparison](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243764289_Between-Group_Comparison_of_Principal_Components) and [Discriminant Analysis of Principal Components](https://bmcgenet.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2156-11-94). Since I'm very new to PCA, I am looking for advice on which method should be employed for this kind of problem.

Particulars of my data are following: 46 data clusters, each a bi-variate distribution formed by two variables measuring different things (so, the units are different). The total number of observations of variables varies between the clusters. One might have dimensions of 150x2, another of 75x2, and yet another 12x2. The clusters are not necessarily Gaussian (that is, the constituting variables have mostly normal distribution, but their joint distribution which is a cluster is often not normal).

Because the variables generating the clusters are of different units, for PCA performed on individual data clusters I first standardize the data. Once I obtain principal components and loadings for each of the 46 data clusters, I need to find a method to compare those results. I have already tried various other distribution comparison methods (like KLD, something based on Mahalonobis distance, etc.), with mixed results.

I work with Matlab and Python, and have no knowledge of R or programs like SPSS.

Comment: Alright, I see how that was totally confusing. Edited now hopefully for further clarity.